# @type and @context from JSON to C#

Tags: json, c#-4.0, google-schemas

**This question has been updatet.**

I wanna get @context and @type from a json string, converted into C# strings in a class.

-- This is my approach --

JSON_STRING

```
{ "@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"question", "normal":"this is normal" }
```

C#

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
json_to_csharp NeedAnswer = (json_to_csharp)serializer.Deserialize(JSON_STRING, typeof(json_to_csharp));

public class json_to_csharp
{
    public string @context { get; set; }
    public string @type { get; set; }
    public string normal { get; set; }
}
```

But @type and @context is null. Only the string normal contains what its suppose to.

I hope someone who can help is out there..

If i use Newtonsoft i would be able to manage it.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

json_to_csharp NeedAnswer = (json_to_csharp)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSON_STRING, typeof(json_to_csharp));

public class json_to_csharp
{
    [JsonProperty("@context")]
    public string context { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@type")]
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string normal { get; set; }
}
```

But i need a workaround when not using Newtonsoft. Thanks ;-)

Comment: What if you strip off `@` like to use `public string context` directly?

Comment: Its still the same if i remove the @ from the class.